# How do I show all the class files that are related(in any way) to an element on my GWT web Application for debugging purpose on the client side?

Tags: java, gwt

I have a sample GWT application called StockWatcher. Consider elements like TextField and Grid. I have a feature where in when I pass, a `?debug=true` parameter in the URL, the application starts showing up the information about the classes related to the elements on my page(like which class it belongs to and which class created that element object) in a ToolTip. I could retrieve the element's class using the `getClass()` method called upon the element.

Now I have a file StockWatcher.java which implements EntryPoint and has the `onModuleLoad()` method. Inside this method I have created new TextField and Grid objects like so:

```
TextField<String> text = new TextField<String>();
Grid g = new Grid();
```

And then there's some other code to manipulate the webpage and it is very large so I'm not presenting it here.

My aim is that, when I open up the browser and the debug mode of my webpage, And I hover over the TextField or Grid which I had created in the onModuleLoad() method of the StockWatcher.java, I want that file name to be shown in the tooltip along with the class name of the TextField and Grid which is:

Desired output:

```
    Parent: com.gwtext.client.widgets.BoxComponent
    This: com.gwtext.client.widgets.form.TextField
    Object created in: com.google.gwt.sample.stockwatcher.client.StockWatcher
```

Now as I mentioned before, its very easy to show the first two components from my desired output using `getClass()` and `getSuperclass()` but I am simply confused as to how to show the third component of my desired output. I cannot be using this.getClass() inside the `StockWathcer` class as there are many such files in my project and I cannot be adding that one line to every file as it will be impossible to do so.

[Desired output screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VB4G.png)

Comment: The main problem here is that the parent-child relationships are all easy to discover at runtime after the structure has been made, while the "created-by" data would mean that every constructor call ever would need to start logging the class that created it and keep that data around for later discovery in a tooltip - which is not something that can be done in a normal JVM or in GWT, at least without some modifications to how either behaves (or more specifics on exactly what you are trying to achieve with this).

Comment: If this is an experimental project, you can fork gwt, and save a Exception in the widget constructor which you can use later to see who instantiated the widget. Hehe don't do that I production 

Comment: This is most certainly not a experimental project. Its already in production. And now so large that I don't know half of the devs. I'm left with facing consequences of not pre-planning for this feature during the start of development. Thanks for both of your help through several posts answers on GWT though!